# WPF CornerRadius turn the Corners to the outside

Tags: wpf, xaml, cornerradius

Im trying to make my own ControlTemplate for an menu. Id like to turn the corners of some items to the outside. So that it look like the Word TabItems, i cant post an image im sry. But i hope you understand what i mean.

Is there a possibility to change the cornerradius like that? or are there other possibilitys?

regards
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to do something like that I often use a Grid with a `Path` drawn in the "corner" sections of the grid.

For example, a tab like the one in word could be drawn as a grid with 2x3 grid. The Top row would spam all 3 cells and contain an object with the top two corner radius set. The bottom row's middle cell would be the Text and the left and right ones would be a `Path` drawn the way you want it.